# Only display certain items in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am a newbie to AngularJS and Ionic framework and using the basic [Starter Tabs Ionic template](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs), I want to be able to "Favourite/Bookmark" some items and display them on a different tab.

My `books.js` structure is as follow:

```
.factory('Books', function() {

  // books data
  var books = [{
    id: 0,
    title: 'Sample Title',
    author: 'Sample Author',
    category: 'Horor, Fiction',
    cover: '/cover.jpeg',
    details: 'some details about the book',
    chapters: [
      {
        id : 1,
        name: 'Chapter 1',
        filename: 'chapter1.html',
      },
      {
        id : 2,
        name: 'Chapter 2',
        filename: 'Chapter2.html',
      }
    ]
  }
  .....  
  return {
    all: function() {
      return books;
    },
    // remove a book from the list
    remove: function(book) {
      books.splice(books.indexOf(book), 1);
    },
```

Now, if I want to be able to add that book to a list, should I create a new array? or does angularJS provide some sort of library which can store that data without actually creating a new list?

I am really not sure how to approach this problem.

**Update # 1:** After looking at Andy's example, I have made the following modifications to the `controllers.js`

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, Books) {

  $scope.books = Books.all();
  $scope.remove = function(book) {
    Books.remove(book);
  };
  $scope.markFavorite = function(book) {
    Books.isFavorite = true;
  };
  $scope.unmarkFavorite = function(book) {
    Books.isFavorite = false;
  };    
})
```

and the buttons :

```
<ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(book)">
    Delete
</ion-option-button>
<ion-option-button class="button-positive" ng-click="markFavorite(book)">
    Fav
</ion-option-button>
```

but using the following ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="book in books | filter:{isFavorite:true}"
```

I can't list favorite books.

Comment: As far a "favourite" is concerned i suggest you add another value to each object of books. Then make them true/false based on user selection then you can simply use `filter` and display all favourites

Comment: @A.J so add another value like `fav : false` for all objects, and use `ng-click` to set each individual item to `true` ?

Comment: Yes, This is what i suggest. If you create a new object then you need to mange both objects. So i would suggest use this.

Comment: can you please provide a sample on how to do this? I am trying it and now I am kind of lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.books = [
    { title: 'Sample Title' },
    { title: 'Sample Title 2' },
    { title: 'Sample Title 3' },
    { title: 'Sample Title 4' }
  ];

  $scope.markFavorite = function(book) {
    book.isFavorite = true;
  };

  $scope.unmarkFavorite = function(book) {
    book.isFavorite = false;
  };

});
```

The view:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <p>All books</p>    
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="book in books"><button ng-click="markFavorite(book)">{{book.title}}</button></li>
    </ul>

    <p>Favorite books</p>    
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="book in books | filter:{isFavorite:true}"><button ng-click="unmarkFavorite(book)">{{book.title}}</button></li>
    </ul>

  </body>
```

[Here's a Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/XqhnFj5htDHJx5KGpaed)

Comment: great example, but I am using a `factory` for the data, to implement your example in my code, would it be something like this ? http://pastebin.com/qv7RGTRi with `isFavorite : null,` variable?

Comment: That's a design decision. If you'd like to mark and unmark favorites with different controllers then it might make sense to put it in the factory.

Comment: I have updated the question, reflecting the changes, I think I am doing something wrong in the controller that I can't list fav books

Comment: oh haha thanks, silly me :) . One quick question, the remove functionality works, but when I close the app and open it again, the removed item is still there. Is that the default behaviour for `splice`?

Comment: Right now your entire application state lives in a single browser session. When you refresh the browser the app is restarted. You could persist changes if you stored them in Local Storage or with [web services](https://www.firebase.com/).